# AS3 Object List Search with Attribute Value Only

Tags: apache-flex, flash, arrays, actionscript-3, object

Suppose I have a list of objects of a certain custom type and I need to find an object given only the value of one of its attributes, how do I do it?

Eg.

```
  // Where user1 ... usern are objects of some class User
  users = [ user1, user2, user3 ... usern ] 

  // How do I find out the objects that have the "foo" attribute set to "bar"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`filter()` method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/Array.html#filter%28%29) of the array:

```
var fooBarUsers:* = users.filter(function (user:User) {
    return user.foo == "bar";
});
```

To sort based on an attribute, use the [`sortOn` method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/Array.html#sortOn%28%29):

```
fooBarUsers.sortOn("foo");          // Sorts in-place by default
```

There are lots of options for the `sortOn()` method; be sure to read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. In case I need to sort based on the attribute, what do I do then?